# How to Configure Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition as Git Default Editor

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I have VS Community 2019 installed. After a reboot, I have the the .gitconfig file opening in Notepad. I want to make VS 2019 my default Git editor and thought I could do this after installing Git. I tried setting the environment variable path (and rebooting) to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd

but it didn't work.

During the Git install process I did not see VS 2019 Community as an option. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use Visual Studio as the git editor.

You can't even find documentation on the subject because I think it is a bad idea so that perhaps explained why no one tried it...

To be a good git editor, an editor must:

1. be very quick to launch
2. open a new instance that git will wait for it's closing

It is recommended to use another lightweight editor: notepad++, Visual Studio Code, ...
Some of them even proposing syntax coloring for git file.